# how tensorflow inference in fp16 with model trained in fp32

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

Is there any seamless way available with best fp16 performance being achieved in NV V100/P100?
E.g. I've a model and implementation being trained in fp32. The App works perfectly. Now, I'd like to explore the experience of fp16. Is there any simple way to enable this.

Comment: i have very similar issue . I want to take my trained fp32 model and run inference with fp16 . Did you figure our or any idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

try this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54457065/9873377), and I found inference with fp16 is faster on Pascal architecture GPU, can someone give an explanation?